# Jquery Trigger the Live event

Tags: jquery, events, live

I have  live event

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.qq-upload-cancel', function() {
```

How can I call it forcibly, for example by other event
I tried

```
$('a.qq-upload-cancel').click();
```

also  trigger and triggerHandler
but it's not work.

I need these because one JQuery Library, had such event, and I want to call it at other event

```
_bindCancelEvent: function(){       
    var self = this,
        list = this._listElement;

    qq.attach(list, 'click', function(e){           
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target ||e.srcElement;                       


        if (qq.hasClass(target, self._classes.cancel)){
            qq.preventDefault(e);

            var item = target.parentNode;               
            self._handler.cancel(item.qqFileId);
            qq.remove(item);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details.  Is the second script is loaded before click is called?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$( 'a.qq-upload-cancel' ).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: -1: `click()` is just a shorthand fort `.trigger( "click" )`, which OP has tried already.

Comment: Right now i think that it's impossible,because of bubble effect